# Angular 2 http request with Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to *

Tags: angular, angular-http

I'm using angular2 and typescript.

I'm trying to post to my mail chimp subscription list.

**My code so far:**

```
 constructor(router: Router, http: Http){   
      this.router = router;

      this.http = http; 
      this.headers = new Headers();
      this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  }

  subscribe = () => {
        var url = "https://thepoolcover.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b0c935d6f51c1f7aaf1edd8ff&id=9d740459d3&subscribe=Subscribe&EMAIL=" + this.email;
        this.isSuccess = false;

        this.http.request(url, this.headers).subscribe(response => {
           console.log(response);
           this.isSuccess = true; 
        });   
  }
```

This is the error I get in my console:

[image]

I get this error now: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

**Current code below:**

```
export class Footer{
  email: string = "";
  router : Router;
  http : Http;
  jsonp: Jsonp;
  isSuccess: boolean = false;

  constructor(router: Router, jsonp: Jsonp, http: Http){   
      this.router = router;
      this.http = http; 
      this.jsonp = jsonp;
  }

  subscribe = () => {
        var url = "https://thepoolcover.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b0c935d6f51c1f7aaf1edd8ff&id=9d740459d3&subscribe=Subscribe&EMAIL=" + this.email;
        this.isSuccess = false;

        this.jsonp.request(url).subscribe(response => {
           console.log(response);
           this.isSuccess = true; 
        });   
  }
```

Comment: i think this problem in server properties see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825429/angular-2-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested

Comment: Please look below answer: [Access Control Allow origin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42547842/6699781)

Answer (score 20):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is something that should be present in the response, not in the request.

If your service supports CORS, it must return it in the response headers to allow the request. So it's not a problem of your Angular application but it's something that must be handled at the server-side level...

If you need more details, you could have a look at this link:

- Understanding and using CORS - http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
- Debugging CORS - http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

**Edit**

It seems that `thepoolcover.us10.list-manage.com` doesn't support CORS but JSONP. You could try to refactor your code as described below:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private jsonp: Jsonp){   
}

subscribe = () => {
  var url = "https://thepoolcover.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b0c935d6f51c1f7aaf1edd8ff&id=9d740459d3&subscribe=Subscribe&EMAIL=" + this.email;
  this.isSuccess = false;

  this.jsonp.request(url, this.headers).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.isSuccess = true; 
  });   
}
```

Don't forget to specify `JSONP_PROVIDERS` when calling the `bootstrap` function.

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/JSONP_PROVIDERS-let.html

Comment: The above call is to mail chimp. Do you know why its complaining? I would of thought the mail chimp would be cross origin

Comment: That error was for trying jsonp, ive added my new code above

Comment: any ideas about the bug above screen shot?

Comment: Perhaps you could make a try with `https://thepoolcover.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json` instead of `https://thepoolcover.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post`...

Comment: I browsed a bit the mailchimp docs and I think that you should use the MailChimp API instead. See this link: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/.

Comment: I'm just looking now. Have you found anything on subscribe to mail lists? I cant see anything

Comment: any ideas? I couldnt find anything for subscribe to a list

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the server side. You have to tell your service to accept GET requests. For example, in JEE with Spring you need to add just:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```