# Angular2 CORS issue

Tags: asp.net, angular, cors

I'm new to angular2 and to be fair I have very few knowledges which I try to fix, however I've run into some issues about cross site request, trying to access a service from another application but I have this issue whatever I try to do

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://hr/Team/EditEmployeeInfo.aspx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:54396' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

This is my angular2 service and I've tried something like this

```
getUserHrtbProfile(userId): Promise<any> {            
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELET');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        var apiUri: string = "https://hrtb/Team/EditEmployeeInfo.aspx?emplid={0}&Menu=InfoEmployee&T=0".replace("{0}", userId);
        return this.http.get(apiUri, headers).map(result => result.json()).toPromise();
}
```

and this is my component

```
this.bannerService.getUserHrtbProfile(this.userId).then(hrtbJson => {
    this.hasHrtbAccess = hrtbJson.HasHrtbAccess;
    this.hrtbProfileUrl = hrtbJson.HrtbProfileUrl;
}).catch(err => {
    this.hasHrtbAccess = false;
});
```

I've search a solution on my problem but still could not find one that suits my need.

> [Angular 2 http request with Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155752/angular-2-http-request-with-access-control-allow-origin-set-to)

But most important, is this an angular2 problem that I need to solve? Or in fact as I've read it should have been handled by the team that exposes the API?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make request on other domain, this is what you can not resolve here. try with making request at you backed code, this will resolve you issue.

Comment: yes i know , it works but not as it should , meaning that i have no idea how the other team did the service but the content is not ok . Imagine an hierarchy in which some users can view other users profile, if i cannot i should receive the 200 because even if i'm not authorized the request is success but the content should be different , well in my case this is not the issue i get 200 and always the same content no matter if i have access or not over some profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable CORS on your API backend.
Only for testing purpose you could use this Chrome Extension to simulate CORS on your api backend:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi