# ionic 2 , error in getting data from server

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i am new to ionic 2 , now i am trying to get the data from host but facing this error . how can i overcome this error . thank you

I am facing this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/jsondata . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

this is my typescript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http , Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})

export class HomePage {

  url:string;
  data:any[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , public http : Http) {

    this.getdata();

  }

  getdata(){

    this.url="http://example.com/jsondata";

    this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe( res =>{
      console.log(res);
        this.data = res;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })

  }

}
```

Comment: which error you are getting ?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/jsondata . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: can you update your question with your json structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 http request with Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155752/angular-2-http-request-with-access-control-allow-origin-set-to)

Comment: @MohanGopi proper url ??

Comment: @rankrunal can you plz tell what change should i do in my above code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running ionic serve the problem is that you are trying to access different domain and your browser is blocking it. You can add plugin to chrome browser to stop blocking. I use Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin. I hope this helps.

Comment: but i have a small doubt ,
will this problem arrive when i am running this application in my mobile ???